# Build Problem with AnysoftKeyboard (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build AnysoftKeyboard in Android studio. 
I have java 9(jdk 9) and the appropriate ndk (android-ndk-r14b), as the creator in GitHub says. 
I have also changed the local.properties file to shows to the correct paths. 
Nevertheless I am still getting some errors. 
You can find below those errors.

Run tasks error : 
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':base:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

java compiler errors : Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/util/JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/util/JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper

Here is a screenshot of the error :
[AnySoftKeyboard Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNniR.png) , [Run Tasks Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4SYC.png)

The project uses gradle, in which I am not familiar with, so if I have missed any important step-point, please guide me to solve it.

Is there something that I am missing and getting these errors? What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After following just the official documentation I successfully built a project. I think **you just forget with setting** `JAVA_OPTS` **with adding** `java.se.*` **source as mentioned below**. And that is why you have it in stacktrace error above, with missing `java.se`. resources.

> To develop this project, you'll need:

- Java 10 - get [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) or [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk10&jvmVariant=hotspot).
- Make sure you have the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'`. This is required to ensure the JVM is merciful with libraries that were not designed for Java9+ JVMs.
- git
- [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install)
- Android SDK API Level 28 installed. Set up `local.properties` file to point to it (that is, ensure you have `sdk.dir=/path/to/android/sdk` in it).
- Android NDK [r14b](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html) installed. Set up `local.properties` file to point to it (that is, ensure you have `ndk.dir=/path/to/android/ndk` in it).

Comment: I have set the variable JAVA_OPTS (this is how it is in my system - JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee)     I finally built it, but not from within Android Studio. I did it from cmd with gradle in project root. I think I faced some certificate errors, but eventually solved them ([link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743987 , [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118). The main problem I am facing is that I cannot change JDK in Android Studio (in order to use JDK 10).

Comment: @ParaskevasPetsanas You built it from `cmd`, because `JAVA_OPTS` need to set within build configuration tab inside Android Studio

Comment: I set it in Android Studio, but I am still getting errors. I think the problem is that I cannot change the android studio default jdk (please choose a valid jdk 8 directory). Do you have any advice ?

Comment: Ok, then in this case, you need to build project via console.

Comment: I tried by settings JAVA_HOME to AdoptOpenJDKversion and JAVA_OPTS in system variable when try to build from cmd its showing JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. How to resolve that?

Comment: @KIRANCSN if you are using linux. Make sure you have imported your variables (Java home and opts) into `.bash_profile` or `.profile` files.

Comment: @GensaGames thanks for replying. But i am using windows OS for building project

Comment: @KIRANCSN If you are setting your local variables throw the Win UI, make sure the path is correct. You should point Java - to Java  Bin location (not AdoptOpenJDKversion)

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/util/JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper

TO remove this error comment below line prone error.